# How to configure expo-leaflet for ImageOverlay

Tags: expo, leaflet

I'm trying to use expo-leaflet with ImageOverlay to generate zoomable maps where I can add some markers from a png file.
I'have some problem to understand how to configure bounds (I think my mistake come from here). My image is loading correctly, but it's deformed.

I want it to be fullsized and with dimensions respected.

For testing purpose, here is my picture : https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/327404.jpg

Here is the result :

[image: Result]

And finally here is my maplayer:

```
  {
    baseLayerName: 'Test Image Overlay',
    layerType: 'ImageOverlay',
    url: 'https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/327404.jpg',
    bounds :[[0,0], [1080 ,1080]],
    baseLayerIsChecked: true,
    baseLayer: true,
  }
]
```